# Change scrollbar colours

Tags: macos, cocoa

I want to change the scrollbar colours for my Mac application. Specifically, I want to change the background colour.

My application is Qt based so the application will already be created and running. I can get the `NSView` for a `QWidget`.

I know I can use stylesheets in Qt to change the look of scrollbars but I would prefer to set an application-wide background colour for the default scrollbars.

I tried `[[NSApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow].backgroundColor = [NSColor grayColor];` but scrollbars remained bright white.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the scroll bar on the right side of [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ojazn.png) is what you are looking for.

In this case, there isn't much you can do with Swift to change that color, because the it is defined by the operating system.

I understand that this solution might not be what you are looking for, since it is not primarily code-oriented, but as far as I know, there is no other way. You will need to first download ThemeEngine to modify .car files. [here](https://github.com/alexzielenski/ThemeEngine/releases).

1. Go to /System/Library/CoreServices/SystemAppearance.bundle/Contents/Resources and copy the file named “System Appearance.car” to any directory that you have permission to write to.
2. Find the image asset with name “ScrollBarOverlay_Track” and replace the default scroll bar background images with your own. I used Photoshop to edit.
3. Save your modified version of SystemAppearance.car, and make sure to include it in the Resources folder of your app.
4. Write the following code when initializing the window:

   ```
    window.appearance = NSAppearance(appearanceNamed: NSAppearance.Name(rawValue: "SystemAppearance"), bundle: nil)
   ```

   This will change the appearance of your window. Replace `window` with your window if you named it differently.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer; it didn't work for me. I dragged the images from ThemeEngine to a Finder window and it copied PNGs. I edited them and dragged them back then saved a new car file. Then I copied to Resources and did `NSView *my_view = (NSView *)(w->winId()); NSWindow *my_win = [my_view window];[my_win setAppearance:[[NSAppearance alloc] initWithAppearanceNamed:@"SystemAppearance" bundle:nil]];`